# XCTest, Failed to load test bundle. Crash on test launch

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

In Xcode 9.1, I added a Unit Test Target to an older project and I'm not able to get tests to run. The target crashes on launch with the following error in the console:

**The bundle “XXXTests” couldn’t be loaded because it doesn’t contain a version for the current architecture***

Full output:

`2017-11-15 11:52:40.973 XXX[54962:16511010] Failed to load test bundle from file:///Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-gaxtmzjadfkxzsdciqnpmyczgntj/Build/Products/DEV-iphonesimulator/XXX.app/PlugIns/XXXTests.xctest/: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3585 "dlopen_preflight(/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-gaxtmzjadfkxzsdciqnpmyczgntj/Build/Products/DEV-iphonesimulator/XXX.app/PlugIns/XXXTests.xctest/XXXTests): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-gaxtmzjadfkxzsdciqnpmyczgntj/Build/Products/DEV-iphonesimulator/XXX.app/PlugIns/XXXTests.xctest/XXXTests: mach-o, but wrong architecture" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try installing a universal version of the bundle., NSFilePath=/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-gaxtmzjadfkxzsdciqnpmyczgntj/Build/Products/DEV-iphonesimulator/XXX.app/PlugIns/XXXTests.xctest/XXXTests, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle doesn’t contain a version for the current architecture., NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “XXXTests” couldn’t be loaded because it doesn’t contain a version for the current architecture., NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-gaxtmzjadfkxzsdciqnpmyczgntj/Build/Products/DEV-iphonesimulator/XXX.app/PlugIns/XXXTests.xctest/XXXTests): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-gaxtmzjadfkxzsdciqnpmyczgntj/Build/Products/DEV-iphonesimulator/XXX.app/PlugIns/XXXTests.xctest/XXXTests: mach-o, but wrong architecture, NSBundlePath=/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-gaxtmzjadfkxzsdciqnpmyczgntj/Build/Products/DEV-iphonesimulator/XXX.app/PlugIns/XXXTests.xctest}`

(And then some diagnostic output that I didn't include)

Stuff I've checked after extensively googling:

- **Build Active Architecture Only** setting is consistent across the app and test targets (With a value of Yes)
- **Enable Testability** is set to Yes for the main target
- I've deleted the target and started over, no luck

How do I fix this?

Comment: What are the "Valid Architectures" for your test bundle? I'm wondering if the intersection of that and "Build Active Architecture Only" is empty.

Answer (score 25):

Make sure `iOS Deployment target` fields of your application target and test target are the same

Comment: In my case Test target had "iOS 12" deployment target, but I was testing on iOS 11 simulator.

Comment: same underlying problem for me with the following error: `xctest (32988) encountered an error (Failed to load the test bundle. (Underlying error: The package „TrackingTests“ could not be loaded because its damaged or has missing resources. dlopen_preflight( .../Debug-iphonesimulator/TrackingTests.xctest/TrackingTests): no suitable image found.  Did find: ( .../Debug-iphonesimulator/TrackingTests.xctest/TrackingTests: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator))`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. Simply building and running the associated application target on an iOS11.1 simulator (which happens to match the "iOS Deployment Target" of Test target) it started working.

It seems starting the test the first time did not trigger a build of the test host. Subsequent runs seem to trigger the builds as needed and all is good.

YMMV

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me when updating the Xcode version from 9.3 to 10. In my case, deleted the DerivedData, then the unit test works.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error. My tests were passing locally but failing on CI (Xcode Cloud). The fix for me was to **set `Enable Hardened Runtime` to `No` for Debug**.

(from https://www.jessesquires.com/blog/2020/02/23/mac-app-tests-fail-with-hardened-runtime/)

Comment: This made it work for me after a lot of testing other things

Answer (score 2):

In my case, The Team under Signing & Capabilities were different for both Target Membership

making the Team same for all Target Membership  solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. And for me what it worked was the following:

- Select your test on the PROJECT NAVIGATOR
- on the right side, in FILE INSPECTOR choose the **Target Membership**, in this case your test target.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had **Mac** version of `OCMock.frameworked` in `Link Binary with Libraries` build phrase for an **iOS** project.

Removing it solved the issue for me.

Answer (score -5):

run with  another ios11 device solve the problem